# Создание Flash приложения для ОС Android

Tags: android, php, actionscript

Есть сайт. Хочу сделать приложение - мобильную версию для ОС Android. На сайте есть статистика. Я сделал динамическое текстовое поле и хочу чтобы цифра онлайн с сайта выводилась в этом поле.

Вот код ActionScript:

```
var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://pokess.ru/flash/php/online.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.load(request);

function completeHandler(evt: Event) {
    var all_on = evt.target.data.all_on;

}
```

Вот код php:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('pokess', $db);

$on     = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM online");
$all_on = @mysql_fetch_array($on);
echo $all_on['count'];
$all_on           = array();
$all_on['online'] = @mysql_fetch_array($on);
$all_on           = http_build_query($all_on);
?>
```

В чем ошибка или как можно сделать по другому, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: @RollerZ, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: не выводит число в поле, а кстати я не знаю куда присобачить имя динамического поля. поле называется "online", подскажите пожалуйста как исправить код

Comment: у одного меня возник вопрос: flash-приложение и Android???

Comment: DroidAlex, в Adobe Flash CS5.5 выбираем AIR for Android. когда открылся документ выбираем "ключик" возле меню выбора проигрывателя, а там все ясно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На последних версиях андройда не работает или некорректно работает flash. Так что лучше вообще отказаться от его использования, лучше заменить на js.